# Can I use more than 4 cases in switch?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am writing application for test jig using Arduino mega 2560, It is menu based program, I'm using Switch-case and I have 6 cases so far, until 4 cases code is working properly, once I'm entering 5th option or trying to access cases from 5th code is coming out of switch.
I have tried using character as well as integer variable as a label, and I've copied 5th case code in 1st and 1st in 5th in this 1st is working fine, I want to highlight that there is no any problem with the statements in case 5th, it is something related to number of cases i can use, basically whenever i want to go to 5th case or any case after 4th program is coming out of switch. can anyone give a brief about it
I'm adding snippet of serial terminal for better understanding...
Appreciate your comments and answers

```
  #include<SPI.h>
//define the SPI and other pins
//SPI: 50 (MISO), 51 (MOSI), 52 (SCK), 53 (SS). for Arduino Mega 2560
#define DATAOUT     51   //mosi
#define DATAIN      50   //miso
#define SPICLOCK    52   //sck
#define TXDSASS     53   //ss
const int RXDSA1SS  =  49;     // to make other digital i/o pins as a SS for multiple SPIs
const int RXDSA2SS  =  48;     // to make other digital i/o pins as a SS for multiple SPIs
const int BPFSS  =  47;       // to make other digital i/o pins as a SS for multiple SPIs
const int POTSS  =  46;       // to make other digital i/o pins as a SS for multiple SPIs

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(DATAOUT,OUTPUT); // to declair the pinMode
  pinMode(DATAIN,INPUT);
  pinMode(SPICLOCK,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(TXDSASS,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RXDSA1SS,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RXDSA2SS,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BPFSS,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(POTSS,OUTPUT);
  
  Serial.println("***Test Jig by Arduino Mega 2560 Welcomes you***");
  
SPI.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println("*************Menu*************");
  Serial.println("1.Enter 1 for Tx_DSA");
  Serial.println("2.Enter 2 for Rx_DSA_1");
  Serial.println("3.Enter 3 for Rx_DSA_2");
  Serial.println("4.Enter 4 for TunableBPF");
  Serial.println("5.Enter 5 for Digital TrimPOT");
  //Serial.println("4.Enter 0 to Exit");

  while(Serial.available() == 0) {} //wait till user provide input on serial 
  if(Serial.available())
   {
      int UserInput = Serial.parseInt();
      Serial.println(UserInput);
      switch(UserInput)
      {
      case 1:   //**********Tx_DSA code**************//
             int choice1; 
             Serial.println("Welcome to Tx_DSA");
             do{          
             Serial.println("Enter Tx Attenuation in dB: ");
             while(Serial.available() == 0) {}//wait till user provide input on serial
             float Attn;
             Attn=Serial.parseFloat();
             Serial.print("Entered Tx Attenuation is: ");
             Serial.println(Attn);
             byte AttnToDSA;
             AttnToDSA = DataToSendDSA(Attn);
             Serial.print("DSA resistor to be set in Decimal: "); 
             Serial.println(AttnToDSA);
             //AttnToDSA = AttnToDSA<<2;
             SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1));
             digitalWrite(TXDSASS,LOW);
             SPI.transfer(AttnToDSA);
             digitalWrite(TXDSASS,HIGH);
             digitalWrite(TXDSASS,LOW);
             Serial.println("Enter 1 for setting Tx_DSA Attenuation");
             Serial.println("Enter 0 for Exit from Tx_DSA");
             while(Serial.available() == 0) {}//wait till user provide input on serial
             choice1 = Serial.parseInt();
             //Serial.println(choice);
             }while(choice1==1);
             break;
      case 2:  //**********Rx_DSA_1 code**************//
             int choice2; 
             Serial.println("Welcome to Rx_DSA_1");
             do{          
             Serial.println("Enter Rx_1 Attenuation in dB: ");
             while(Serial.available() == 0) {}//wait till user provide input on serial
             float Attn;
             Attn=Serial.parseFloat();
             Serial.print("Entered Rx_1 Attenuation is: ");
             Serial.println(Attn);
             byte AttnToDSA;
             AttnToDSA = DataToSendDSA(Attn);
             Serial.print("DSA resistor to be set in Decimal: "); 
             Serial.println(AttnToDSA);
             //AttnToDSA = AttnToDSA<<2;
             SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1));
             digitalWrite(RXDSA1SS,LOW);
             SPI.transfer(AttnToDSA);
             digitalWrite(RXDSA1SS,HIGH);
             digitalWrite(RXDSA1SS,LOW);
             Serial.println("Enter 1 for setting Rx_DSA_1 Attenuation");
             Serial.println("Enter 0 for Exit from Rx_DSA_1");
             while(Serial.available() == 0) {}//wait till user provide input on serial
             choice2 = Serial.parseInt();
             //Serial.println(choice);
             }while(choice2==1);
             break;
      case 3:  //**********Rx_DSA_2 code**************//
             int choice3; 
             Serial.println("Welcome to Rx_DSA_2");
             do{          
             Serial.println("Enter Rx_2 Attenuation in dB: ");
             while(Serial.available() == 0) {}//wait till user provide input on serial
             float Attn;
             Attn=Serial.parseFloat();
             Serial.print("Entered Rx_2 Attenuation is: ");
             Serial.println(Attn);
             byte AttnToDSA;
             AttnToDSA = DataToSendDSA(Attn);
             Serial.print("DSA resistor to be set in Decimal: "); 
             Serial.println(AttnToDSA);
             //AttnToDSA = AttnToDSA<<2;
             SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1));
             digitalWrite(RXDSA2SS,LOW);
             SPI.transfer(AttnToDSA);
             digitalWrite(RXDSA2SS,HIGH);
             digitalWrite(RXDSA2SS,LOW);
             Serial.println("Enter 1 for setting Rx_DSA_2 Attenuation");
             Serial.println("Enter 0 for Exit from Rx_DSA_2");
             while(Serial.available() == 0) {}//wait till user provide input on serial
             choice3 = Serial.parseInt();
             //Serial.println(choice);
             }while(choice3==1);
             break;
      case 4:    //**********BPF code**************//
             int choice4;
             word Freq = 0;
             String FreqHex;
             Serial.println("Welcome to TunableBPF");            
             do{ 
                Serial.println("Enter BPF Frequncy: ");
                while(Serial.available() == 0) {}//wait till user provide input on serial  
                Freq = Serial.parseInt();             
                Serial.print("Tx Frequncy: ");
                Serial.println(Freq);
                SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
                digitalWrite(BPFSS,LOW);
                SPI.transfer16(Freq);
                digitalWrite(BPFSS,HIGH);
                FreqHex =  String(Freq, HEX); 
                Serial.print("Frequncy to be set to Tunable Band Pass Filter in HexaDecimal: ");
                Serial.println(FreqHex); 
                Serial.println("Enter 1 for setting BPF Frequency");
                Serial.println("Enter 0 for Exit from BPF");
                while(Serial.available() == 0) {}//wait till user provide input on serial
                choice4 = Serial.parseInt();
               }while(choice4==1);
               break;
       case 5:     //**********Digital TrimPOT code**************//
              int choice5;
              int Voltage;
              SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(5000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
              digitalWrite(POTSS,LOW);
              SPI.transfer(0x1082);    //Set default value i.e. 28V in NV register
              SPI.transfer(0x30);      //Copy NV Register to Wiper Register (Default Value: 28V)
              digitalWrite(POTSS,HIGH);
              Serial.println("Welcome to Digital TrimPOT");            
              do{
                 Serial.println("Enter Voltage to set on Digital POT: ");
                 while(Serial.available() == 0) {}//wait till user provide input on serial 
                 Voltage = Serial.parseInt();
                 Serial.print("Entered Voltage: ");
                 Serial.println(Voltage);
                 float R3 = 1.65*((Voltage/1.7)-1);
                    Serial.println(R3);    
                 float RegValue = ((R3/50000)*256)*1000;
                    Serial.println(RegValue);                
                 digitalWrite(POTSS,LOW);
                 SPI.transfer16(RegValue); //Write to Wiper register
                 digitalWrite(POTSS,HIGH);           
                 Serial.print("Register value to be set in Wiper Register: ");
                 Serial.println(RegValue);
                 Serial.println("Enter 1 for setting Digital POT Voltage");
                 Serial.println("Enter 0 for Exit from Digital TrimPOT");
                 while(Serial.available() == 0) {}//wait till user provide input on serial
                 choice5 = Serial.parseInt();                                
               }while(choice5==1);
               break;
        case 6: Serial.println("In 6th case");
              break;
        default: Serial.println("Invalid Entry, Please enter valid choice");
    
      }
      Serial.println("out of Switch");
   
  }
}

int DataToSendDSA(float Attenuation)
 {
   int DSAAttn=0;
   String AttnHex;
     //int Attenuation=Attn;
     int Binary[]={32,16,8,4,2,1};
     float AttnStep[]={16,8,4,2,1,0.5};
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<6;i++)
     {
     if(AttnStep[i]==Attenuation)
      {
        DSAAttn=DSAAttn|Binary[i];
        break;
      }    
     else if(AttnStep[i]<Attenuation)
      {
        DSAAttn=DSAAttn|Binary[i];
        Attenuation=Attenuation-AttnStep[i];
      }
     }
      DSAAttn=DSAAttn<<2;
      AttnHex =  String(DSAAttn, HEX); 
      Serial.print("Attenuation to be set to DSA in HexaDecimal: "); //remove this print after development
      Serial.println(AttnHex); 
    return DSAAttn;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: You need to post your code if you want some help

Comment: Please do not post images of text, you can copy/paste the text itself which makes it easier for other people to refer to parts of it. If you want help with your code you must post it. See [how to ask a good question](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange).

Comment: `I want to highlight that there is no any problem with the statements in case 5th, it is something related to number of cases i can use, basically whenever i want to go to 5th case or any case after 4th program is coming out of switch` - actually there are problems in the switch statement. You need to post it to get an answer to that.

Comment: `basically whenever i want to go to 5th case or any case after 4th program is coming out of switch` - what do you mean by that? What is printed in the serial monitor? Do you see "Invalid Entry, Please enter valid choice"? Or what?

Comment: @NickGammon, When I'm choosing 5th case, program is coming out of switch. it is not going in default as well. you can see attached snippet of serial terminal, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than 4 cases in a switch statement. In fact, there is no limit, apart from the fact that you cannot have duplicates.

Your problem is somewhere else, in your code which you sadly have not posted.

---

I'm not sure if this is your issue, but I am getting compiler warnings:

```
sketch_dec24a:153: error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]
```

This is caused by declaring variables inside each case label. I suggest putting them in blocks, eg.

```
  case 3:  //**********Rx_DSA_2 code**************//
         {   // <---- add this
         int choice3; 
         Serial.println("Welcome to Rx_DSA_2");
         ... blah blah ...
         break;
         } // <---- add this
```

Do this for every case label that has variable declarations in it. Or, move the declarations outside the switch statement.

Comment: Thank you Nick, I'm trying to paste my code it is not pasting in proper format, please help me in that.

Comment: See the link I mentioned. [How to ask a good question](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange). In particular the section *Post your code, formatted correctly*.

Comment: Basically paste your code, select it all, and then type Ctrl+K.

Comment: I have edited my post, Please check the code. Thank you

Comment: Also, I suggest to transform each case into its own function.

Comment: @NickGammon It worked for me, I have made blocks for each case as well as same variable for choice taken out from case...Thank you so much